# IsEmpty check returning wrong value for TextEditingController

Tags: flutter, dart

**The Problem**

The `isEmpty` check is returning `true` for a non-empty String field. My guess is - TextEditingController's String metadata is not updating with string update from an async load.

1. I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious or if this is a Dart/Flutter bug.
2. Is there an idiomatic way to accomplish this check?

**Here's my code**

```
  var textController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }

  void init() async {
    final foo = await FooProvider.instance.getFoo(widget.uuid);
    textController.text = foo.title;
  }
```

The actual usage of the textController,

```
GestureDetector(
                onTap: textController.text.isEmpty
                    ? () {
                        debugPrint('Empty - ${textController.text}');
                      }
                    : () {
    // rest of the code
```

**Output**
(With actual field value "abc")
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the text of `TextEditingController`, your widget wouldn't be rebuilt automatically.

Because `setState` never has been called.

### Solution

1. (Recommended) Wrap `textController` with `ValueListenableBuilder` if you want to listen value changing.

```dart
ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: textController,
      builder: (context, value, child) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: textController.text.isEmpty
              ? () {
            debugPrint('Empty - ${textController.text}');
          }
              : () {},
        ); 
      },
    );
```

2. (Not recommended) Call `setState` manually if `textController` value changed.

This will rebuild entire widget tree of your widget.

```dart
  void init() async {
    final foo = await FooProvider.instance.getFoo(widget.uuid);
    
    setState((){
      textController.text = foo.title;
    });
  }
```

3. Evaluate `isEmpty` in `GestureDetector.onTap`

by @Ivo 's comment you can check `isEmpty` in `onTap`. This works because `isEmpty` is evaluated at time `onTap` called.

```dart
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            if(textController.text.isEmpty) return;
            // not empty
          },
        )
```

Comment: thanks! From the look of it - it's working now.
I'm still curious - how come the value is getting updated but the isEmpty property isn't taking that into consideraion.

Comment: Your `build` function hasn't been called again.  It means `isEmpty` doesn't be evaluated again after data changed. So `GestureDetector` is having old information about `onTap` parameter.

Comment: @Fallen I think what you need to realize is that actually `textController.text.isEmpty` is not checked in the `onTap`. `textController.text.isEmpty` determines which of the `onTap` implementations is assigned to the `GestureDetector`. You could alternatively have made a single `onTap` implementation and check `textController.text.isEmpty` inside of it. This could also have worked instead of relying on a rebuild

Comment: Great, I did append my answer.

Comment: @MJStudio ah I also added it as a separate answer, but it's okay

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to do the check inside a single implementation of `onTap` instead of two different ones, like this

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
                    if (textController.text.isEmpty) {
                      debugPrint('Empty - ${textController.text}');
                    } else {
                      // rest of the code
                    }
                  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Ivo for filling in my knowledge gap. This does indeed explain my confusion.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer as it has both parts covered.

@Ivo - For the sake of posterity, it would be great if you could combine your explanation to this issue from the other comment to this answer.

Comment: @Fallen I'd rather have you keep the other answer accepted. I think MJ Studio deserves most credit